# gst_element_request_pad_simple fails for hlssink2

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, http-live-streaming, openh264

My appsrc pipeline is as follows:

appsrc-openh264enc-h264parse-hlssink2

I first retrieve each element with gst_element_factory_make successfully, each element is checked for nullptrs.

Then I add/link all the elements with 'always' presence via:

```
gst_bin_add_many(pipeline, appsrc,h264Encoder,h264Parse, NULL);

assert(gst_element_link_many(pipeline, (GstElement*)appsrc, h264Encoder, h264Parse, NULL));
```

According to the gstreamer plugin docs, h264parse as a 'src' has 'always' but hlssink2 as 'video' is 'request'. So, I try to retrieve the pad to link the two:

```
//hlspad returns null
GstPad* hlspad = gst_element_request_pad_simple(hlssink2, "video");

//videoParsePad is non-null
GstPad* videoParsePad = gst_element_get_static_pad(h264Parse, "src");
```

This is native side on Android, anyone know why this isn't working? Everything should be compatible

Comment: Hi, 

Are you sure hlssink2 is available ? and splitmuxsink ? ( splitmuxsink is used by HLS sink )

you could also use this in one line, if you need :
gst_element_link_pads(h264Parse, "src", hlssink2, "video");

Comment: The hls plugin links and gstreamer successfully retrieves the hlssink2 element, so I'm pretty sure it's available. Didn't see anything in the docs that said its not on Android

Comment: could you try :
gst_element_factory_make("splitmuxsink", "splitmuxtest") and says me if it's variable is not null.

Comment: Tested it just now, splitmuxsink is non-null.

Comment: Using hlssink with mpegtsmux instead of hlssink2 works, good enough workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hlssink instead of hlssink2 works, good enough workaround

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).